# Dynamically add php file

Tags: php

I want to include php files dynamically using include in IF statement.

```
    if($php_var != "Home") {
        include "files.php";
    } else {
        include "Home.php";
    }
```

Problem is that it is not working. For some reason it freezes the menu bar such that when I click any other option it does not work.
Now, Could it be that the include statement freezes all other scripts or are the two files conflicting? Would greatly appreciate help!

Comment: The syntax is correct, therefore any issues would have to be caused by the content of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if($php_var != "Home") {
    if php_check_syntax("files.php")
        require_once("files.php");
    else
        echo "File not Valid";
} else {
    if php_check_syntax("Home.php")
        require_once("Home.php");
    else
        echo "File not Valid";
}
```

Or

```
function loadPHP($file)
{
    if(file_exists($file))
    {
        if php_check_syntax($file)
            require_once($file);
        else
            echo "File not Valid";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "File do not exist";
    }
}

if($php_var != "Home") 
{
    loadPHP("files.php");
} else {
    loadPHP("Home.php");
}
```

Comment: Not really.  It will work happily enough without parentheses - test it.

Comment: Instead of saying "you should use", it's better to say "you probably want to use" - the OP may have a good reason why he uses include (e.g. continue if file not found versus abort)

Comment: @Hzakv I just tested it on my linux box - works fine.

Comment: i already edited my post :) sry. are your files in same path ?

Comment: @Hzakv if my hint was useful or helped... please don't forgett to vote up and may except the answere :)